# Laravel: Missing required parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I got the error `missing required parameters`, with the following route:
`Route::get('/myunits/{group}/content/{unit}','Users\GroupContentController@show')->name('user.group.unit.show');`

The route is correct when we redirect to that route, but for some reason It fails. But when I do a dd() of the parameters on `GroupContentController@show` the parameters are there, so I don't understand where is the error.

This is my controller

```
public function show(Group $group , Unit $unit) {


    /*
    * Check if the user is trying to acces a group
    * here he does not belongs.
    */
    if ( !UserGroupFacade::IsStudentInGroup($group) ) {
        return redirect()->route('user.groups');
    }

    $data = [];
    $groupMaterials = $group->groupMaterials->where("unit_id" , $unit->id);

    foreach ($groupMaterials as $gm) {
        foreach ($unit->themes as $theme) {
            if ($theme->id == $gm->theme_id) {
                $theme->show=true;
                $material=$theme->materials->where("id" , $gm->material_id)->first();
                $material->show=true;
            }
        }
    }

    $data['unit'] = $unit;
    return view('users.units.show', array('data' => $data));
}
```

When I did a dd($group) and dd($unit) everything was there, even I tried that before the return and It stills working.

The html that should be displayed is the following:

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('title')
  Unit
@endsection

@php
  $unit = $data['unit'];
@endphp

@section('content')
  <section class="goal-app-header-section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="image-div float-content left thirty">
        <img style="width: 182px; height: 182px; object-fit: contain; border-radius: 50%;" src="{{ $unit->image }}" alt="Unidad">
      </div>
      <div class="description float-content right seventy">
        <h1> {{ $unit->name }} </h1>
        <p class="description"> {!! $unit->description !!} </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="bars-section">
    <div>
      <div class="text-center bars blue float-content left half">
        <div class="row"><h2> Themes </h2></div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center bars green float-content right half">
        <div class="row"><h2> Media tools </h2></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>


  <section class="content-section">

    <input id="view-name" type="hidden" value="single-unit-view">
    <div>
      <div class="float-content left half">

        <?php $number = 0; ?>
        @foreach ($unit->themes as $index => $theme)
          @if ($theme->show)
          <?php $number++; ?>
          <div id="{{ $number }}" class="leftArrow inactive">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-1 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-1">
                <div class="numberCircle"><div class="number">{{ $number }}</div></div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
                <p class="left">
                  {{ ($theme->title) }}
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          @endif
        @endforeach

      </div>

      <div class="content-list float-content left half">
        <?php $number2 = 0; ?>
        @foreach ($unit->themes as $index => $theme)
          @if ($theme->show)
          <?php $number2++; ?>
          <div id="course-content-{{ $number2 }}" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-left course-content">
            @foreach ( $theme->materials as $material )
              @if ($material->show)
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-height col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-1 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-1">
                  <svg>
                    <image style="height: 20px;" href="{{ $material->icon() }}"/>
                  </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
                  <a target="_blank" href="{{ $material->resource_url }}" class="left">
                    {{ $material->title }}
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              @endif
            @endforeach
          </div>
          @endif
        @endforeach
      </div>


    </div>
  </section>


@endsection
```

Finally this is the place when I call the desired route

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('title')
  My Groups
@endsection

@php
  $group = $data['group'];
  $units = $data['units'];
@endphp

@section('content')

<section class="goal-title-section">
  <div class="container white space-at-bottom">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-center">
        <h1 class="black">{{ $group->name }}</h1>
        <hr class="black">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-center">
       <div class="black">
       {!! $group->description !!}
       </div>
       <p class="black">
        This group has the folowing units:
       </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <section class="units-grid">

    @foreach (array_chunk($units, 4) as $unitsRow)
        <div class="row">
            @foreach ($unitsRow as $unit)
                <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-3 col-md-offset-0 col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-0">
                    <div class="card text-center">
                      <img src="{{ $unit->image }}" alt="Unidad">
                      <h5 class="black">{{ $unit->name }}</h5>
                      <a href="{{ route('user.group.unit.show', ['group'=>$group->id, 'unit'=>$unit->id])}}" class="btn goal-btn goal-btn-blue goal-btn-small">Read more</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endforeach

</section>

  </div>
</section>

@endsection
```

Comment: post your html code as well

Comment: The html code is there now

Comment: where are you calling this route /myunits/{group}/content/{unit} in your view

Comment: I put that code now, is almost at the end of the last code

Comment: have you try to return $group and $unit ?

Comment: Yes, and it works, for some reason it works on local but not on the server.

Comment: okay.do one thing remove one of the paramter from the url and then try to return one and then second again.
may be group or unit is empty in your db.

Comment: That can not be possible, If the unit was not created or the group, I couldn't get to the view where I call the desired route.

Comment: okay.then copy and paste the link/url you are getting in inspect element

Comment: https://my-site/myunits/2/content/1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176094/discussion-between-salman-zafar-and-jacobo-tapia).

Comment: The answer below works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

can you just make route like this and put dd($group,$unit) in your controller to see what you sent to it.

```
Route::get('/myunits/{group?}/content/{unit?}','Users\GroupContentController@show')->name('user.group.unit.show');
```

Comment: have you made the parameters optional like what i sent to you.